# Migrate data between different orgs using Heroku Connect

Tags: migration, data-migration, backup, heroku-connect

Is there a way to migrate data from a salesforce organization to another via heroku connect preserving the relationship between objects?

Heroku connect allow you to easily synchronize your data bidirectionally between a Salesforce organization to a postgres db.

It seems possible to export data from an org to another (using a sort of workaround) but I can't understand if exists a way to mantain the relationship between records.

Eg.
If I have Case1 and Account1 on FS2 related through a lookup relationship, I need to migrate Case1 and Account1 and the relationship between them to FS1

Use case scenario:

I have two full sendbox orgs FS1, FS2. I need to close FS2, but first I need to export some important test data from FS1 to FS2.

My final need is about finding a way to "easily" migrate data between two different SFDC organizations.

P.

Comment: check this out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce